# Is Adobe Flash available for ARMv6 devices? 

Tags: adobe-flash

Is it possible to have flash working or ARMv6 devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official flash player for android only supports ARMv7 processor architecture.
The way that some ARMv6 devices have flash is that some is that a few cheap tablets (usually from China) have a non-official version.

You can download one [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1155538). But beware it may or may not work!

Answer (score -2):

You have Flash Player which is pre installed on your device. You can have (some) luck with running .swf files. I tried running it in the browser and it was a bit glitchy.

Comment: He does **not** have flash player, because the phone he's using is not supported hence the question.

Comment: How do you know what model his phone is? I've a Legend which is ARMv6 and has Flash Player. Flash Player is for those devices that can't run Flash.

Comment: Oh my god you seriously have no idea what you're talking about about do you? You need flash player to run flash. Your device doesn't runs a full flash player just a dumbed down light one.